# css property applied to wrong element with ngStyle in Angular 4 on ngFor

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular2-directives, ng-style

I'm trying to change the background color of an element dynamically added to the array of elements from the 4th button click on in my component.html like this:

```
    <button class="btn" (click)="toggleContent()">Display Details</button>

    <div class="left-align left-div">
      <div class="center-align" *ngFor="let counter of count" >
        <p [ngStyle]="{backgroundColor: blueBackground()}" [ngClass]="{whitetext: counter > 4}">{{ counter }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

After the 5th click all elements in the array get the colored background instead of those, which were added after the counter got more than 4. At the same time the ngClass directive works well on the same condition, and only the text in the elements after the 5th click gets white. Here is my component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styles: [`
    .outer-div {
      height: 20px;
      margin: 20px;
    }
    .left-div {
      width: 50px;
      margin-top: 5px;
    }
    .inner-div {
      border: 2px solid lightblue;
      height: 20px;
      margin: 20px;
    }
    .whitetext {
      color: white;
    }
  `]
})
export class AppComponent  {

    count = [];
    counter: number = 0;

    toggleContent() {
      this.counter ++;
      this.count.push(this.counter);
    }

    blueBackground() {
      return (this.counter > 4) ? 'lightblue' : 'white';
    }

}
```

What am I overseeing ... ?

Comment: So you want the blue background only on the 5th element?

Comment: yes,  on all the consequent elements from the fifth element on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is when you write `<p [ngStyle]="{backgroundColor: blueBackground()}"..` and increment `this.counter`, it will effect all the elements because every change detection tick will update all the current elements that have this binding. Hence when the counter is above 4 every element will update itself.

Rather than updating your counter manually you can take advantage of `ngFor`'s `index` property.

Example:

```
<div class="center-align" *ngFor="let counter of count;let i = index" >
      <p [ngStyle]="{'backgroundColor': (i+1 > 4) ? 'lightblue' : 'white'}" [ngClass]="{whitetext: counter > 4}">{{ counter }}</p>
</div>
```

Plunker example: http://plnkr.co/edit/QECx8Jd2nP8PnrqzcD89?p=preview

Comment: That works! But what's the matter with updating it through the function? I can't quite put my finger on it.

Comment: @AndreyK when you bind the method to your `p` elements it's not a one time thing. They will be waiting for `this.counter` to change. You will need a specific flag for each element, in order to distinguish them from the others; like an id (index in this case). With what you did you are basicly saying that all `p` elements inside this loop are bind to the `this.counter` field and when it is above 4 change the backgroundColor to lightblue. Hence they do :-)

Comment: thanks a lot for the explanation. I understand now, that this is different with using the ngStyle and ngClass without a method.